# How I can check the amount of checked checkboxes in the array of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got 2 arrays of checkboxes: `country` and `groups`:

[image: arrays]

How can I check how many checkboxes are checked?

**I've tried countries.$('input:checked').length - but it doesn't work.**

```
function checkBoxSelect() {

      var countries = countryList.find('input[type="checkbox"]');
      var groups = groupList.find('input[type="checkbox"]');

      console.log(countries);
      console.log(groups);


}
```

Comment: please add relevant code in a fiddle

Comment: Added a fragment of my function

Comment: Have you tried `countries.length`

Comment: use groupList.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

Comment: @AllanJebaraj it's always preferable to have the code in a stack snippet on this site, so the question is self-contained. External links can expire and would make the question worthless for the future.

Comment: Yes @VLAZ I understand that. But the OP initially posted the question with just an image that's why I requested for some code.

Comment: @AllanJebaraj point was that requests should be made for the code to be on-site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise to use [jQuery#filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, which will give you better readability and flexibility.

```js
const $checkBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked');

console.log($checkBoxes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = arrayOfElements.filter(function(){
 return $(this).is(':checked');
})

console.log(c.length)
```

Comment: Hi. Please edit your answer to include some explanation of how this code solves the problem. This will make your answer more understandable and useful to the OP and to anyone else who has this problem in future. Thank you.